# Hiding Source code

Tags: asp.net

i have a problem in my website.i need to disable both right click and view source option in browsers menu for all webpages.There may be some other ways to get source code,that doesn't matters.i have alredy disabled right click.so please help me if there is any way to supress browsers view source option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no point; if the browser can see the source, then so can anyone else.  Disabling right-click, etc. is just irritating; it's *my* browser, not yours.

Comment: I can just download your page with curl and see the source code, and you can't do anything about it. If you want to make your javascript/css hard to read, there are tools out there to minify your code and obfuscate it.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? HTML, JavaScript and CSS will always be visible in some form. Preventing people from viewing them simply isn't possible.

Comment: just to prevent end users to get the source code directly from the browsers menu.we can't restrict all the ways but i dont want to allow them to get source code in this two ways.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - Which browsers have that? I don't see anything in FF or Chrome. Obviously, you could do it with a GreaseMonkey script (which is another reason not to try to disable right-click).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - Found it in FF. The option is called "Disable or replace context menus". TIL...

Answer (score 5):

The best way to hide your html source code is to not send it at all to your client. The problem is the client will not be able to see your site. If you do want him to see your site, you have to send him something he can render. If you send something, anyone will be able to read you source. There is no magical way to show something with is not there.

Answer (score 1):

Stepping back from the vitriol comments, including my own which I apologize was too harsh, it occurs to me that this is an opportunity to explain *why* what you seek is in vain.

When a server sends down a response to a browser, it is not sending a compiled application. Rather, it is sending ***instructions*** mingled with data. What you are requesting is the ability to send instructions without the recipient seeing the instructions. An analogy would be:

> I want to provide instructions to Grandma's house without the recipient
>   seeing the instructions.

In addition, the recipient is at liberty to ignore any or all of those instructions. Using our analogy, it would be as if the last line in the instructions was `Don't read this`. As peer suggested, the only way to avoid someone reading an instruction is not to provide it.

Be mindful that you are only sending instructions to the user's browser about how to format data; not control their machine. Much like robbing user focus, if you attempt to send instructions that alter the user's native browser functionality, it is considered ***extremely rude***, will only annoy users and they can easily ignore those instructions. Also consider that all browsers have native developer tools which let you see the markup, the JavaScript and the CSS and there is no way to disable these.

In conclusion, it isn't possible to disable the View Source option nor is it possible to prevent users in anyway from viewing the source you send to the browser. In addition, there are many tools which will disable your right-clicking nerf. So, given that it isn't possible prevent a user from seeing the source, the better question that should be asked to your team is *why*. Why are you attempting to conceal the source in the first place?