# Restricting the downloading static files from webbrowser in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have problem that i need to restrict the user to download static files from my website
like .css and .js files using url.for that i have created one httphandler and i've written some code
to redirect the request to my login page.It is blocking the requests for .js files successfully but
along with that it is not allowing my website to use that .js file.is there any way to do that?

Comment: If you are blocking download, how do you expect a browser will (be able to) use it?

Comment: You should probably go back and read the answers to your question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733154/hiding-source-code to understand why it is not possible

Comment: never tried to restrict files like this, not sure what benefit the end user would get from them? what happens if you add them in the App_themes ? not sure if this is a restricted directory?

Answer (score 0):

We can use Http Module to check if the URL contains these specific extensions. For example, we create an http module in the App_code folder and configure the http module in the web.config:

```
namespace HttpUrlRewrite
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for HttpUrlRewrite
    /// </summary>
    public class Rewriter  : System.Web.IHttpModule
    {


        public void Init(System.Web.HttpApplication Appl)
        {
            Appl.BeginRequest += new System.EventHandler(Rewrite_BeginRequest);
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
        }


        public void Rewrite_BeginRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
        {
            System.Web.HttpApplication App = (System.Web.HttpApplication)sender;
            string path = App.Request.Path;


            string strExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path);
            if (strExt == ".css")
            {
                //Do Something
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("error.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                //Do Something
            }


        }
    }
}

                <httpModules>
                        <add type="HttpUrlRewrite.Rewriter" name="HttpUrlRewrite" />
                </httpModules>
```

Comment: i have added the same code.i am using iis5.1.so when i have given request for .js files that event was not fired.so i have created the Handler for .js files.Then event fired.but now i am getting the problem that my .js file is not accessible to both website and request for .js